# Standard way of returning backbone collection in requirejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I've seen different examples in different articles about how to return a Backbone collection (or View, for that matter) from a RequireJS define. For example:

```
define(['models/person'], function( person ) {
    var personCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: person,
        url: "api/person"

    });
    // do this?
    return new personCollection();
    // or this?
    //return personCollection;
});
```

Is there a memory advantage to either approach? Is there standard design pattern that dictates which should be used?

The same question would apply to views, as I've seen them done both ways too.

Comment: How are you planning to use it? Do you want one collection (ie, `define` is being used to define a singleton) or the definition of the collection?

Comment: Maybe that should be my next question :-) Is it recommended to share a single definition of collection, e.g. if the collection is fetched by one widget then it doesn't need to be fetched by another. Or does that create a lot of possibility for overlapping and conflicting updates?

Comment: I believe that it is a good idea to share collection if it fetches from same endpoint, that way you avoid multiple request and can rely on collection events to update your UI.

Comment: I believe in the second option you would want to remove the parenthesis (return personCollection;). That way you're just returning the class that can be instantiated at will. If you leave the parenthesis, I believe you are instantiated the object with 'this' being the window object (not what you want).

Comment: @robmisio was typo, fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the second way, because then you would receive reference to "blueprint" not the object itself. In most cases one should want to initialize object creation itself.

Also, even if you want only single instance of collection created I would advise using factory method like this:

```
define(['models/person'], function( person ) {
    var personCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({...}),
        singleCollection,
        export = {
          getInstance = function (options) {
            if (!singleCollection) {
              singleCollection = new personCollection(options);
            }
            return singleCollection;
          }
        }

    return export;
});
```

And then you could call it like this:

```
require('models/person', function (person) {
  var personCollection = person.getInstance(options);
}
```